# Determine if thousandth or hundred or tens

Tags: javascript

How to determine if a number is tenthousandth, thousandth, hundredth, tens.  I need to convert them to their nearest.

For example, 124. since it's hundredth, i will convert it to 200 using

```
Math.ceil(124/100) * 100
```

For example, 4560. since it's thousandth, i will convert it to 5000 using

```
Math.ceil(5000/1000) * 1000
```

Comment: calculate the length?

Comment: Check the length, do log10, do a modulus division. There are plenty of ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following way to convert given number into nearest 10

```
function convertToNearest(num){

    var mul = 1;

    while(num > (mul * 10))
        mul = mul * 10;

    return Math.ceil(num/mul) * mul;
}
```

Comment: convertToNearest(4260) should return 4000

Comment: @Rafael in fairness, OP called it "nearest" but then explained "next in the same order of magnitude" - `124` -> `200`

Comment: yeah, kudos for a quick solution :)

Comment: thanks, this works, although i just need to change it to Math.ceil

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev That was my mistake. It was ceil and then I told him 4260 should've returned 4000.

Answer (score 0):

This solution handles integers (positive AND negative):

```js
function nearest(n) {
 if (n === 0)
  return 0;

 let neg = (n < 0);
 if (neg)
  n = -n;
 let x = 10 ** Math.floor(Math.log10(n));
 if (x === 1)
  x = 10;
 let ans = Math.ceil(n/x) * x;
 return (neg) ? -ans : ans;
}

[-230, 0, 1, 8, -18, -6540, -120, -5, 12, 4560, 320, 888, 83293, 2323203]
 .forEach(n => console.log('%s\t->\t%s', n, nearest(n)));
```